# How to set active class on my list menus and submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I tried this to my code given below is not working on me... once I click the anchor the page will load then the active class is set to default. I want to set the list active and submenu too using jQuery.

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled menu-categories" id="accordionExample">
  <li class="menu active">
    <a href="#dashboard" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <div class="">
        <i data-feather="home"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="menu">
    <a href="#User" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <div class="">
        <i data-feather="user"></i>
        <span>User</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <i data-feather="chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
    
    <ul class="collapse submenu list-unstyled" id="User" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <li class="">
        <a href="../User/UserMaster"> UserMaster </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="../User/UserRoleMaster"> UserRoleMaster </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="../User/MenuAccess"> MenuAccess </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: __once I click the page will load:__ after load jquery will not recognize active inactive. based on url data only you have to apply active inactive

Comment: What code? I see no JavaScript. Did you search? This topic has come up quite often over the many years Bootstrap has been popular.